# Разрушен до основания

Tags: этимология

Добрый день. Помогите разобраться.
"Город разрушен до основания." Это как? Значит до фундамента?
Зарание спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Конечно истории известны случаи, когда непокорный город захватчики в буквальном смысле сравнивали с землёй, а землю эту перепахивали посыпая солью, чтобы тут не могли снова поселиться люди, но это скорее исключение, чем правило.

Как правило под разрушенным до основания городом (домом, сооружением) имеется в виду такая степень разрушения, что построить новое здание уже проще и дешевле, чем восстанавливать старое. Так после похода Батыя, многие русские города были опустошены до такой степени, что  оствшиеся в живых жители сменили место расположения города. Такая судьба постигла, например, Рязань.